# How to grant Read access to parent Account when Opp is shared through Sharing Set?

Tags: community, partner-communities, sharing-sets

In a Partner Community, I'm granting edit access to Opportunities that have the User's Contact record indicated in a specific Contact lookup field on the Opportunity.

However, users that get this Opportunity access are not able to view the parent Account. I thought that Opportunity access always implied read-only Account access. Is this not the case in Communities/Sharing Sets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit Read access to parent Account from an Opportunity is not granted if Opportunity access comes from a Sharing Set. I had to write Apex to insert AccountShare records to deliver this.

Comment: Sharing sets are not used for partner community licences so you have used the right option with using account sharing records.

Comment: Just as a side note for future readers, this is also possible in a Flow, as you can create AccountShare records there, too